# Make my own file extension (That start's my program)

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I built a Software in vb.net that you can draw in it, and save your drawing in
a .GFrame file.

My Software work's great, it save file and open file successfully.

but I have one problem, I want that when I am Trying to open a .GFrame file it will Automatically
open my Software and load that file.

For example :

if you will try to open a .BTM file it will Automatically open  "Paint" program and load the file to screen.

So how can I do the same thing in my Software ?

Comment: [Does this help?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d89af73d-3ad7-485a-b6c4-94dadf13659e/how-do-i-associate-a-file-extension-with-my-application?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: It helped me a bit, but I still don't know how to get the file name that was opened. I need the file name for the Software, to know from Which file the Software will load (data).

Comment: You need to create a [file association](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749986.aspx).  That's done by a setup program, any setup creation utility supports that.  You get the file name from the command line, Environment.CommandLine or the Sub Main() argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 steps:

1 - As mentioned above you need to update your program to handle a command line parm being passed to it; the command line parm of course being the name of the file (including its extension) that you want your program to handle.

2 - Also, as mentioned above, you need to have this built into your setup file.
Here is how I did it, using Inno Setup (free) for the skin files ending with the extension (.ar4w) which I associate with my program (A Ruler for Windows):

[Registry]

Root: HKCR; SubKey: .ar4w; ValueType: string; ValueData: A Ruler for Window skin; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Languages: ; Tasks: Associate_ar4w_files

Root: HKCR; SubKey: A Ruler for Window skin; ValueType: string; ValueData: A Ruler for Window skin; Flags: uninsdeletekey; Tasks: Associate_ar4w_files

Root: HKCR; SubKey: A Ruler for Window skin\Shell\Open\Command; ValueType: string; ValueData: """{app}\aruler.exe"" ""%1"""; Flags: uninsdeletevalue; Tasks: Associate_ar4w_files

Root: HKCR; Subkey: A Ruler for Window skin\DefaultIcon; ValueType: string; ValueData: {app}\arulerlowres.ico,0; Flags: uninsdeletevalue; Tasks: Associate_ar4w_files code here

3 - Not yet mentioned above, if you want to open these files from your website you have add a line into your .htaccess file as well - here is the one I use:

AddType application/x-arulerforwindows ar4w

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here the sub main method...the other is very similar for when your app starts with a mainform:

```
  Public Sub Main(ByVal args() As String)

     ' multiple files might be passed, decide whether to work with them all:
       For n As Integer = 0 To args.Length - 1
           ' do something
      Next

      ' or just the first one:
      mFileName = args(0)
   End Sub
```